# Google Cloud Storage : Google Cloud Storage JSON API to fix Access Not Configured error 403?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using an `HTTP POST` request to upload a file onto Google Cloud Storage.

Request is:

```
POST /upload/storage/v1beta1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=media&name=testFile HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 24
Content-type: text/plain
Authorization: OAuth ba26.AHXXXXXXXXXVHXdVRAhBAHR_UXXXXXLV-MqPMXXXJwc

<BINARY DATA - 24B>
```

I am getting the following error as the response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

Somewhere I read that I need to switch on Google Cloud Storage JSON API.
Is it compulsory to switch on ***Google Cloud Storage JSON API*** 
or is there any other solution to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the JSON API, it must be enabled. Enable the JSON API by visiting the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console), clicking APIs, and enabling the "Google Cloud Storage JSON API"

Comment: I was testing from localhost, ran into this exact error, followed this solution with one addition. Localhost needed a "Simple API Access" "API Key" that had "Referers" set to "Any referer allowed" by deleting all the referers and saving.

Comment: I enabled "Google Cloud Storage JSON API" but still receiving same error! any help?

Comment: @Susim Waiting a couple minutes was necessary for me.